# TeXMaker shows errors after compilation for deleted lines

Tags: errors, texmaker

I'm using an old TeX document as a template. As I did just copy the TeX related files and none of the pictures of the former document it always gave me errors for the "legacy chapters" of the document, but it always created the `.pdf`.

Now I decided to get rid of the legacy parts to not get any errors and have a useful log file, to actually check for errors in my part. But TexMaker continues to give me errors for lines that don't even exist anymore in the document. On top of that it doesn't create the `.pdf` file anymore and I couldn't tell why (not even from the messy log).

Does someone know if I have to delete some other files belonging to the document?

Cheers for any help,

Peter

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Are you sure you compile the new file and not only the template?

Comment: Did you delete the auxiliary files as well (`.aux`, `.bbl`, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue is determined by your old auxiliary files.

In TeXMaker, go to the "Tools" menu and launch the command "Clean".

This deletes (more or less) all auxiliary files generated by the compiler (`.aux`, `.bbl` and so on).

Now try to compile your document again. You shouldn't get all those errors, but only the ones related to the document you are actually dealing with.

Comment: interesting. I did delete them manually before (also the hidden files), but that didn't work. The clean command did. Thank you very much karlkoeller.